# How to copy keyframes from one object to another?

Tags: keyframes

I would like to know how I can copy keyframes or better a complete Animation to another object, so both objects have the same Animation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the non animated object, Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> And select the animated one, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> >> Animation Data.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Good Luck